# Stop loss and take profit at the same time on binance

Tags: stop-loss

I found on some articles that in order to place a stop loss and a take profit at the same time for a long order, one should buy a market order and sell a stop limit order (with the stop loss value for the stop price and price) in a ddition to sell a limit order (with the take profit value as a limit) but it’s not working if the take profit was hit.
In that case, we still have a stop limit order which is executed if the stop loss was then touched.
Do you have a working idea to get the SL and TP added to a trade?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need it's an OCO order ("One Cancels the Other"). In a nutshell, what you are doing is the following:

> An OCO, or “One Cancels the Other” order allows you to place two orders at the same time. It combines a limit order, with a stop-limit order, but only one of the two can be executed.
> In other words, as soon as one of the orders get partially or fully filled, the remaining one will be canceled automatically. Note that canceling one of the orders will also cancel the other one.
> When trading on the Binance Exchange, you can use OCO orders as a basic form of trade automation. This feature gives you the option of placing two limit orders simultaneously, which may come handy for taking profit and minimizing potential losses.

Check the official [documentation](https://academy.binance.com/tutorials/what-is-an-oco-order) for more details.

Comment: Actually i need it for futures and it's not available in binance API for this kind of products...

Comment: @Valometrics.com I know this question is dated and you probably already have the answer, you can place a pair of reduce-only orders (1 stop limit, 1 limit).